# Configuring Jersey with Spring boot

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-boot, jersey

I am trying to configure the spring boot with jersey but it seems jersey annotations are not working with spring boot.
can you please help me out.

I have tried @RestController  instead of @Component and @RequestMapping instead of @Path  in service class.

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hotel</groupId>
    <artifactId>reservations</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>reservations</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!--  lookup parent from repository  -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Spring Boot Application Xml**

```
package org.hotel;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReservationApplication {

    public static void main(String []args){
        SpringApplication.run(ReservationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**service class with jersey annotations**

```
package org.hotel.webservices;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Component
@Path("/rooms")
public class AddRoomService {

    @GET
    public String addRoomService(){
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice tutorial online about this:
[Spring Boot Jersey Example July 14, 2017 by Lokesh Gupta](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/). This seems to be the part you're missing.

**Jersey Configuration**

1: Now we have a JAX-RS resource and we want to access it from spring boot application which include Jersey dependency. Let’s register this resource as Jersey resource.

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig 
{
    public JerseyConfig() 
    {
        register(UserResource.class);
    }
}
```

Look at the @Component annotation. It enables this class to be registered while spring boot auto scans the java classes in source folder.

2: `ResourceConfig` provides advanced capabilities to simplify registration of JAX-RS components.
3: Extend spring boot application with `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JerseydemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new JerseydemoApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder    (JerseydemoApplication.class)).run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `@Component`, I wasted hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer from Nicholas agreed its an excellent tutorial but if you wish to restructure the project (for example create multiple packages for your resources, models etc) you must ensure that the JerseyConfig class and JerseydemoApplication class are in the same package, otherwise the registration wont work. This is not explicitly mentioned in the tutorial.

I found this while working in intellij ultimate edition and following same tutorial provided by Nicholas above